# Is there a precedent for Romulans settling honor battles in a sword fight?

Tags: star-trek, romulan, star-trek-picard

In [PIC:1x04 "Absolute Candor"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Absolute_Candor_(episode)) - we see [Picard](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jean-Luc_Picard) challenged to a sword fight by [Romulans](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Romulan) on the planet [Vashti](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vashti).

In the episode we see Picard tear off a sign, 'Romulans Only' and stomp on it, to challenge their tribalism. In that sense he picks the fight. The Romulans talk of their prior knowledge of Picard. They drag him outside and put a sword in his hand.

This leaves two possibilities:

1. They [know](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/We%27ll_Always_Have_Paris_(episode)) of Picard's sword fighting [skill](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Fencing) and are seeking a fair fight on his terms.
2. Sword fighting is a common way to solve matters of honor in Romulan culture.

**Is there a precedent for Romulans settling honor battles in a sword fight?**

Comment: I don't think Romulans are even aware of the concept of "honor" from TOS to DS9. Maybe their culture (d)evolved into some warrior society on that planet due to the exodus and continued refugee status instead of continuing as the cloak-and-dagger society they used to be.

Comment: I think PIC is introducing us to the idea that there is no single "Romulan culture". It may be that these particular Romulans have swords as a part of their culture. It could also be that disruptors are scarce in their colony and they have adopted the use of swords out of necessity.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz, maybe they're just Klingonboos, but use more practical swords instead of Klingon antler-"sword" Bat'leth?

Comment: @Morfildur This is the right take. “Precedent for Romulan honor—…” Whoa, whoa, let’s stop right there with the crazy talk.

Answer (score 2):

There is some slight precedence for this in the book **Spock's World** by Dianne Duane.  One of the greatest sword makers in Vulcan history is living at the time of the Romulan split, at which time the Vulcans gave up the use of swords for violence and only continued to make them for art.  The would be Romulans, of course, came to no such enlightenment.